# SQL Query to mark entries of n2n relation

Tags: mysql

Happy last Day of 2011!

I have some troubles finding the right query for my probelm.

I have two tables (mails, customers) which are connected via the third table: mail_has_customers. One can find out, that there are mails, which will be sent to several customers. It's an n2n relation. One mail could have more customers and one customer could have several mails.

I want to check one special mail with the `id_mails (PK) = 2`. The Result should list all customers and mark those, which are connected to my current mail.

Here are the tables (pseudo)defined:

```
mails(id, subject, content, PK: id);
customers(id, name, PK: id);
mail_has_customers(id_mails, id_customers, FK: id_mails, id_customers);
```

My current query looks like following code, but the problem is, I get the customers twice, or more which have more then on mail-connection.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, (CASE WHEN hc.id_mails = 2 
   OR hc.id_id_mails IS NULL 
   THEN hc.id_mails
   ELSE  'x'
   END
) AS selected
FROM customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN mail_has_customers hc ON hc.id_customers = c.id
ORDER BY c.id, selected ASC
```

I had also tried `DISTICT ON`, but that somehow didn't work with mysql. Or did I use wrong Syntax? `SELECT DISTINCT ON(c.id, c.name) c.id, c.name, (CASE...`

UPDATE:

I also tried to `GROUP BY c.id` that stuff, but then I get the first entries (order by id) which overwrite the later entries of selected and I don't find out if it be possible marked for id_mails = 2.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do a distinct or a group by unless there are duplicates in either your customer table or mail_has_customers table; or the relationships are not what you have described.

If you must the syntax is

```
Select distinct C.ID, C.Name, (CASE WHEN hc.id_mails <> 2 
   OR hc.id_id_mails IS NULL 
   THEN hc.id_mails
   ELSE  'x'
   END) as Selected
```

However, the logic that's bothering me is the case.

currently you have case when hc.ID mails =2 OR hc.ID_id_Mails is null.

- the ID_ID seems incorrect based on your table structure
- the logic of looking for 2 and null is perplexing if you just want only the 2's to be selected per stated requirements.
- In addition I'm assuming ID is numeric yet your trying to get a result that is numeric and character by casing in an 'X' as selected.

Do you need the HC.Mail_ID in your results?  if you do you will have multiple entries for customer thus perhaps the appearance of duplicate customers, though not duplicate records as the hc.id_Mails makes them unique.

So shouldn't the query look something like

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, (CASE WHEN hc.id_mails = 2 THEN 'x' else null END) AS selected
FROM customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN mail_has_customers hc ON hc.id_customers = c.id
ORDER BY c.id, selected ASC 
Group by C.ID, (CASE WHEN hc.id_mails = 2 THEN 'x'  else null END)
```

The group by only being needed if customer or hc records are duplicated in the base tables.